# regular expression with alphanumeric with all special chars excpet with %

Tags: java, regex

regular expression with alphanumeric with all special chars excpet with %

Length of string must be 1 to 12.

trying this way (as regex), but this is allowing % also.

```
[[^=][\w\S][^-]]{1,13}
```

example my input string (itemValue) for above pattern, should give false:   `test%t1z`

```
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexStr);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(itemValue);

            if(matcher.matches()){
                flag = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of:

```
String regexStr = "[^%]{1,12}";    # If whitespaces are allowed
String regexStr = "[^%\\s]{1,12}"; # If whitespaces are disallowed
```

Note that `Pattern#matches` requires a full string match, thus, there is no need adding anchors like `\A`/`\z` to the regex pattern.

*Details*

- `[^%]{1,12}` - matches any one to twelve chars other than `%`
- `[^%\s]{1,12}` - matches one to twelve chars other than `%` and whitespace

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/g6HfNd):

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("abc123#67812", "abc123%67812", "abc123#678120");
String regexStr = "[^%\\s]{1,12}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexStr);

for (String itemValue : strs) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(itemValue);
    System.out.println("\"" + itemValue + "\": " + matcher.matches());
}

// => "abc123#67812": true
//    "abc123%67812": false
//    "abc123#678120": false
```

Comment: this is working, but I did not get your notes:
Note that the anchors are redundant when the regex check is performed with Pattern#matches as this method requires a full string match.

Comment: @mgr The patterns above will behave as if there were `\A` at the start and `\z` at the end. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Qv8dm/2).

Comment: one more requirement, could you able to help for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606645/regular-expression-for-3-words-with-alphanumeric-with-all-special-chars-excpet