# regular expression (for 3 words) with alphanumeric with all special chars except with % -

Tags: java, regex

regular expression with alphanumeric with all special chars except with % - in the words.

it is 3 word separated with hyphen. first and second word can allow anything except % -
Third word is only digits

**first word**

1. not be empty (i.e. not a simple white space). but it can allow spaces in between.
2. can not contain % and -
3. length must be 1 to 10

**second word**

1. not be empty (i.e. not a simple white space). but it can allow spaces in between
2. can not contain % and -
3. length must be 1 to 12

**third word**

1. not be empty (i.e. not a simple white space)
2. only digits allowed
3. length must be 4 to 9

trying this way (as regex), but this is allowing % also.

```
[[^%\-\s]]{1,10}[-]{1}[[^%\-\s]]{1,12}[-]{1}[\d]{4,9}
```

allowed strings:

```
"1sAS-c$AS-01238"
"t t-c:t-012345678"
"t$t-c 2:t-012345678"
```

Not allowed strings:

```
"1sA%S-c$AS-01238"   (because this contains % in the first word)
" -c:t-01235678"     (because this contains only space in the first word)
"t$t- -01234578"     (because this contains only space in the 2nd word)
"t-$t-check-012378"  (because this contains more hypens)
```

example my input string (itemValue) for above pattern, should give false: test%t1z

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexStr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(itemValue);

        if(matcher.matches()){
            flag = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String regexStr = "(?!\\s+-)[^%-]{1,10}-(?!\\s+-)[^%-]{1,12}-\\d{4,9}";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iafd1K/1/).

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string (implicit when the regex is used with `matches()`)
- `(?!\s+-)` - immediately to the right, there should not be one or more whitespaces and then a `-` char
- `[^%-]{1,10}` - one to ten chars other than `%` and `-` (`[^%\n-]` does not allow to match a newline in the demo)
- `-`  - a hyphen
- `(?!\s+-)` - immediately to the right, there should not be one or more whitespaces and then a `-` char
- `[^%-]{1,12}` - one to twelve chars other than `%` and `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{4,9}` - four to nine digits
- `\z` - end of string (implicit when the regex is used with `matches()`).